# Is it possible to show a double sided reversible skirt through animation?

Tags: animation, materials, rigging, transforms, cloth-simulation

I have been trying to animate a skirt using Blender. The skirt is worn by a character and is it double sided which means it can be reversed inside out to reveal the other side with a different design.

Is it possible to use cloth simulation and character rigging to make the character turn the dress inside out with hand movements linked to the belt of the skirt?

Comment: That sounds like some complex animation and simulation for just after finding out if it's possible... Anyway, how does that even look in real life? Do you have some video, that you could at least use as a reference? I mean... I don't even know how it's done in real life, do you?

Comment: I do have a reference video for a real life version but don’t know if it’s possible in blender to pull it off

Comment: We know you don’t know if it’s possible. I’m glad you have a reference video. Can you show that to us so we can tell you if it’s possible or not?

Comment: Ofcourse, where can I send you the video